# loading xml file in java web app

Tags: java, servlets, loading, classloader

I need to load log4j.xml config file in my web to initialize logging. log4j.xml is in package
com.test.config.

when in j2se java app code

```
InputStream input = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/test/config/log4j.xml");
```

resturns input stream but when I execute this in servlet it returns null.
servlet is java web app deployed on glassfish 2.1

what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If the `log4j.xml` file is in a jar file, ensure that you've added the jar file to the servlet classpath in Glassfish.

Otherwise, if its in a directory, say `resources/com/test/config` you have to add the `resources` directory to your server classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the current thread's context class loader `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` instead, I think this solved a similar issue for me once.